$E \wedge BC$ for height $n$ cohomology theories
Let $E$ be a ring spectrum underlying a complex oriented cohomology theory of the kind studied in Section 5 of Hopkins–Kuhn–Ravenel's paper Generalized group characters and complex oriented cohomology theories.
Let $A$ be a finite cyclic group. HKR prove that $E^*(BA)$ is free of finite rank over $E^*(\mathrm{pt})$. Is it true that the smash product
$$E \wedge \Sigma^\infty BA$$
is isomorphic to a finite direct sum of copies of suspensions of $E$?

This will typically be false.  However, for many E it will be true that the K(n) localization of the smash product is such a finite direct sum.

@JeremyHahn That's a lot of useful information. Would you mind giving a reference or further details for your statement about the K(n)-local category?
